# Can't open IIS manager

Tags: iis-7, iis

Folks,

Very strange issue here - I simply cannot open the IIS 7 manager by choosing it directly.

My OS is Windows 7, and as such, I can see it's opened on the Start Menu aswell as a preview of the window itself when I hover over it. I cannot however, see the actual window itself. I can click it on the task bar (it does 'start'), and it doesn't report any errors - it's as though the window will not maximise...

Even more strangely, I can open the IIS manager by starting the MMC and adding the IIS Manager snap in - which works fine...

Any thoughts?

Cheers,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wonder if it's on a "2nd monitor", what happens if you right click on the taskbar icon, and select move, and then move it to your main monitor? Does that bring it back?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, but this is definetely not the problem :(

Comment: Can you telnet to the host/port that it's listening on- i.e. is it really listening? (also, have you tried a reboot?)

Comment: I've tried a reboot and the IIS process itself is still working. Following your suggestiong though, I had a closer look - http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/bring-misplaced-off-screen-windows-back-to-your-desktop-keyboard-trick/ - this sorted it. Thanks for the suggestion problem solved. Boy do I feel stupid :)

Comment: We have all done it- glad your problem is solved :)

Comment: By the way, if you run Inetmgr.exe /reset it will run and reset its preferences which includes the starting position which would also "fix" the problem

Comment: Thanks! I was using Remmina Remote Desktop Client with "Use client resolution" and my IIS was out of my screen. I wasn't able to move the window (maybe because some Remmina limitation), but just restarted the client with a custom resolution and it worked.

Comment: I can't believe the problem was just that. I have reinstalled IIS several times and searched everywhere. Thank you !

Answer (score 17):

I found a  new solution. First, when we get this error IIS Manager couldn't appear. Go to IIS Manager and right click to go `Properties`. On the shortcut section you can see `Run` line. Change this value to `Maximized` and  click Apply or OK. Open IIS Manager again.

Comment: It's insane that this worked for me - ty so much.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

After just experiencing this problem myself the solution I found in the end was to open task-manager shut down explorer.exe in the Processes tab, maximize IIS in the Applications tab and then run explorer.exe as a new task.

I am aware of the age of this thread however I just had this happen to me on a machine running Server 2008 R2 and this post was the only related article I could find so I'm hoping my contribution will help a future user in need.

Comment: How do you "run explorer.exe as a new task"?

Comment: I figured it out, go to File -> Run in Task Manager, type in "explorer" and hit enter

Answer (score 1):

Do you have MOSS installed?  If so, check this. [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946517)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Chris - I tried working through that but it hasn't had any effect so I don't think this is the issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Tried the solutions above this is the only thing that worked. Task manager > Expand IIS manager > Maximize

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If right clicking on the shortcut does not present you with the Maximize option then wait until a window hovers over the shortcut (assuming it's pinned to your task bar and your mouse is on the shortcut) then right click the window. Maximize worked for me. Glad I didn't do a reset or install/uninstall

IIS10 running on Windows Server 2019 Standard

Answer (score -1):

Based on other answers here, you can click the IIS Manager link, hit Alt+space and hit maximize or move

Comment: Note that other answers already post have this, but with more/better presentation.

Comment: I didn't noticed any of then mentioning the keyboard shortcut to perform the operation, that is easier than opening the Task Manager and sometimes the right click does not work, so, it's remain useful